# sending variables using POST in window.location method

Tags: php, jquery

I am using following code to pass variable to another page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnExportpdf").click(function(){
var html= $("#tblExport").html();
window.open('pdf.php?html='+html, '_blank', 'scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,fullscreen=yes,status=no');
  });
 });
```

I am getting an error 
[image]

I think this problem is due to length of URL. So how can I do it another way ?

Actually I want to send contents of one html page to another Php file,where the contents of file are converted into pdf

Comment: this is not `post` ..its `get`

Comment: `POST` that HTML, instead of `GET`

Comment: I am beginner to PHP. Can u give me a link to sample code, so that I can look for and use it

Comment: This isn't PHP code. It's javascript code. If you want to send data via POST method, look for AJAX.

Comment: Here you are passing the full HTML, not just a variables, or any post values. So check it again

Comment: Show your html code of `#tblExport`

Comment: or use `cookies`, if you want to do window.open only?

Comment: Actually I want to send contents of one html page to another Php file,where the contents of file are converted into pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the passed HTML code, it would be better to directly write it to the window:

```
var win = window.open('pdf.php', '_blank', 'scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,fullscreen=yes,status=no');
win.document.write(html);
```

EDIT:

Ok, in this case the easiest 2 options are:

1. Send a POST form (if the HTML is in a form element)
2. Send the HTML code via ajax

Ajax example:

```
$.post("pdf.php", { html: html });
```

In `pdf.php` you can read the html value like normal post variable:

```
$html = $_POST['html'];
```

Read more about ajax post:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Actually I want to send contents of one html page to another Php file,where the contents of file are converted into pdf

Comment: I have used this code, and am able to post parameter. Now how can I open the file to which I posted parameter in a new window,like I have used window.open function in my code given above. I am beginner to web development. Give me a easily understandable code please

Comment: You want a popup for the success message? With a popup window you'll get problems with popup blockers. Why not use something like [that](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)?

Comment: No I dont want pop up, actually in the other page , am converting the posted content into pdf using mpdf

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do..Do you want to open the pdf in a new window after creation?